# graphs in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph

I'm new to html5 and trying to display an array of code in a graph. It works for a line graph but for some reason unknown to me not for an exponential one. this my code.

My question is, is there a fault in the code that would break the graph?(i'm sure there's a metric ton of mistakes in the code).

I also got a lot of my code here.

thanks in advance for any help I receive.

the values are : `f5 = 8`, `xpos5 = 100`, `sDI5 = 6.4` and `rI5 = 1280`.

```
<canvas id="graph5" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

function generateTestData5() // generates the array 
{
    var data = [];
    for(var i=0; i<300; i++){
        var sensfi = ((document.getElementById("f5").value)*(document.getElementById("xPos5").value)*(document.getElementById("f5").value))/((i*i*document.getElementById("sDI5").value)/(document.getElementById("rI5").value));
        data[i] = sensfi;
    }
    return data;
}

var graph;
var xPadding = 40;
var yPadding = 40;

function getMaxY5() {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    var max = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        if(data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }

    max += 10 - max % 10;
    return max;
}

function getXPixel5(val) {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    return ((graph.width() - 20) / data.length) * val + (20 * 1.5);
}

function getYPixel5(val) {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    return graph.height() - (((graph.height() - 20) / getMaxY5()) * val) - 20;
}

function draw5(){
    var data = generateTestData5();
    graph = $('#graph5');
    var c = graph[0].getContext('2d');

    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
    c.textAlign = "center";

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
    c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.lineTo(graph.width(), graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.stroke();

    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {

        if(x==30) {
            c.fillText(i, getXPixel5(i), graph.height() - yPadding + 20);
            x=0;}
        else {
            x++;
        }
    }


    c.textAlign = "right";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";

    for(var i = 0; i < getMaxY5(); i += getMaxY5()/10) {
        c.fillText(i, xPadding-10, getYPixel5(i));
    }
    c.strokeStyle = '#f00';
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(getXPixel5(0)+10, getYPixel5(data[0])-20);

    for(var i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {
        c.lineTo(getXPixel5(i)+10, getYPixel5(data[i])-20);
    }
    c.stroke();
    //c.clearRect(0,0,graph.width(),graph.height());     
}
```

Comment: Consider editing your original post instead of posting an (almost entirely) identical one. Just use the edit button in the linked post to add the missing information.

Comment: I answered your original post.